# How to do server side sorting in data tables

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I have used data tables in one of my project, all things are working fine except ordering, we want to use server side sorting, I tried lots of examples but it is not working for me,can anyone please help me to do sorting, I am stuck in this issue, here is my code

```
episodes_data_table = $('#episodes_table').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "pageLength": 20,
        "dom": 'trip<"clear">',
        //"dom": 'trilp<"clear">',
        "aaSorting": [[0, "desc"]],
        "ajax": {
            type: "post",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>billing/get_episodes_data",
            data: function (d) {
                return jQuery.extend({}, d, {
                    "branch_id": current_branch_id,
        "month": $(".month-filter-input").val(),
        "year": $(".year-filter-input").val(),
                });
            }
        },
        "fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {
        },
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "data": "ID",
                "render": function (data, type, row) {
                    return data;
                },
                "targets": 0,
                "visible": false,
                "bSortable": false,
            },
            {
                "data": "LastName",
                "render": function (data, type, row) {
                    return data;
                },
                "targets": 1,
                "visible": true,
                "bSortable": false,
            },
            {
                "data": "MRN",
                "render": function (data, type, row) {
                    return data;
                },
                "targets": 2,
                "visible": true,
                "bSortable": false,
            },
            {
                "data": "SOC",
                "render": function (data, type, row) {
                    return data;
                },
                "targets": 3,
                "visible": true,
                "bSortable": false,
            },
            {
                "data": "EpStart",
                "render": function (data, type, row) {
                    return data;
                },
                "targets": 4,
                "visible": true,
                "bSortable": false,
            },
            {
                "data": "EpEnd",
                "render": function (data, type, row) {
                    return data;
                },
                "targets": 5,
                "visible": true,
                "bSortable": false,
            },
            {
                "data": "PhyFirstName",
                "render": function (data, type, row) {
                    return data;
                },
                "targets": 6,
                "visible": true,
                "bSortable": false,
            },
            {
                "data": "SNVisits",
                "render": function (data, type, row) {
                    return data;
                },
                "targets": 7,
                "visible": true,
                "bSortable": false,
            },
            {
                "data": "HHAVisits",
                "render": function (data, type, row) {
                    return data;
                },
                "targets": 8,
                "visible": true,
                "bSortable": false,
            },
            {
                "data": "MSWVisits",
                "render": function (data, type, row) {
                    return data;
                },
                "targets": 9,
                "visible": true,
                "bSortable": false,
            },
            {
                "data": "PTVisits",
                "render": function (data, type, row) {
                    return data;
                },
                "targets": 10,
                "visible": true,
                "bSortable": false,
            },
            {
                "data": "OTVisits",
                "render": function (data, type, row) {
                    return data;
                },
                "targets": 11,
                "visible": true,
                "bSortable": false,
            },
            {
                "data": "STVisits",
                "render": function (data, type, row) {
                    return data;
                },
                "targets": 12,
                "visible": true,
                "bSortable": false,
            },
            {
                "data": "TotVisits",
                "render": function (data, type, row) {
                    return data;
                },
                "targets": 13,
                "visible": true,
                "bSortable": false,
            },
        ]
    });
```

Can anyone please look at the code and give me the proper solution ? Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: I have implemented server side datatable that can be linked with any kind of database and in this sorting, pagination, searching every thing is under your control. Check this github example link : https://github.com/pandeyz/Jquery-Datatable---Server-Side-with-Custom-Inline-Editing

Comment: Thanks, finally it is working now,thanks for your help